# European energy production figures and graphs

Tags: electricity-generation

I'm interested in the breakdown of energy production by individual EU country.

For the [EU I found this site](https://ec.europa.eu/energy/en/content/energy-modelling-interactive-graphs?type=stackedarea2d&themes=s_38_gross-electricity-generation-by-source&second_scenario=undefined&index_year=#container-charts-controls), it's good, but it does not offer the kind of breakdown I'm interested in - I'd like to see it in the format of 'stacked, one country, at a time' (i.e. all energy production, but one country at a time) rather than showing the country comparison 'sector by sector' (e.g. all solar for all countries).  I could download the data from here to a .csv file, but if something exists online, that would be better and easier to use.

I live in the UK and what I'd like is something like the UK [Gridwatch site](http://gridwatch.co.uk/) which shows an interesting summary just for a single country; I am particularly interested in the 6 large electricity production graphs on this site (daily, monthly and yearly) - ideally I would like to see something similar for any other European countries.

**Additonal**

Limitations of the EU website.

[image: EU website screen shot]

Comment: This question is indeed not good for [electronics.se], and it is fine here, but you may get better/more answers at [opendata.se]. If you do not get good answers here, you can post your question there later. There are already [some questions on energy production](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq+energy+production) there

Comment: Are you after live data or historic? That EU site **does** show it stacked one country at a time, for all electricity generation: what do you want it to do, that it doesn't already do? And are you interested in electricity production, primary energy consumption, or supplied energy?

Comment: Jan - thanks for the feedback and the link, I'll take a look at that.  @EnergyNumbers - thanks for the comment, I'm interested in electricity production (and actually the sorts of energy consumed, be it from electricity, gas or renewable).  The EU site shows either a country:energy type breakdown or an All EU stacked graph:a single energy type.  I'm particularly interested in the 6 large graphs (daily, monthly and yearly electricity production output) - I'll update my question to make it clearer.

Comment: If you tick "Gross electricity generation by source" and "Select All Countries", doesn't that give you what you want? That's a stack of all countries, of electricity production from all fuels summed.

Comment: No, I want to see just one country at a time - plus the graph shows a 'shadow' of the total EU production.  I'd like to see one country on a graph, with a stacked line, each part of the stack would represent one energy source.  Sorry for being fussy...I know all the data is there on the site.  It could that searching by individual countries, rather than EU, would be more fruitful.

Answer (score 1):

Electricity production in [Germany](https://www.energy-charts.de/power.htm)

Electricity production in [Spain](https://demanda.ree.es/visiona/peninsula/demanda/acumulada/2018-07-30)

Electricity production in [France](http://clients.rte-france.com/lang/an/visiteurs/vie/prod/realisation_production.jsp)

Ah, it seems I've hit [the jackpot](https://windeurope.org/about-wind/daily-wind/electricity-mix?utf8=%E2%9C%93&areas=PT%2CGB&commit=Apply%20filters), Windeurope.org has data per country and per electricity source.  You can pick and choose which countries you want to view.  They also have some interesting summaries on wind generated electricity too - Denmark, UK and Portugal doing very well on their wind turbines at the time of writing.

[Global link](http://www.tsp-data-portal.org/Historical-Electricity-Generation-Statistics#tspQvChart)

ALSO - see this [excellent post](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/7377/examples-of-near-real-time-energy-dashboards-or-portals) on the OpenData Stack Exchange, thanks to Jan Doggen for finding this!